# JavaFX setPrefWrapLength() method

Tags: java, javafx

It doesn't matter in the following code whether i pass the value 50 or 300 to the function. all my buttons are always in a row unless i resize the window. According to theory after the row of my nodes reaches 50 pixels (suppose i pass that value to the setPrefWrapLength() method) my next node should be in the next row. But that is not happening. Can someone explain me why?

```
package test2;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKConstants;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn1 = new Button("one");
        Button btn2 = new Button("two");
        Button btn3 = new Button("three");
        Button btn4 = new Button("four");

        FlowPane fpane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 10, 10, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4);
        fpane.setPrefWrapLength(50);

        Scene scene = new Scene(fpane, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Flow Pane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**update :**
I found out the following line in the javaFX documentation and i think this is in context with this question

> Note that prefWrapLength is used only for calculating the preferred size and may not reflect the actual wrapping dimension, which tracks the actual size of the flowpane.

Comment: It's only a preferred value and can be overridden during the layout pass. I believe it depends on the size of the flowpane itself because by design a row must be filled before the new one starts. If your flowpane is 300 wide then it won't start a new row at 50. I suggest you override Region for a more custom implementation.

Comment: So are you suggesting me to make my scene narrower?

Comment: Making the scene narrower would work but hardcoding a width to get the desired effect isn't good practice if you want to resize the window at all. I tend not to use any of the provided layouts and always create my own custom subclass of Region (see the documentation) which has always worked.

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of having such kind of functionality in the first place. Suppose i want my buttons only upto a certain width from the left  and the region after that i want  to add something else. I think this was created to tackle that kind of problem (p,s i would only like to use FlowPane for this)

Comment: I know it seems counterintuitive right, in my experience however, it has always been the better choice. I disagree, I do not think flowpane is designed for that at all and I would be very impressed if you got that to work. I don't know how exactly you want stuff layed out but it sounds like you will need nested layouts inside, for example, a HBox.

Comment: Why do you only want to use FlowPane?

Comment: Because i am learning that and it kills me to watch not being able to make something work. That's it.

Comment: It makes no sense to learn something by applying it to a problem for which it was not designed and then get irritated when it does not work.

Comment: First, we don't know what is the actual use of this function and how do we apply it. So I thought why not ask about it. What's wrong in that?